# How to extract data from dropdown list using python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to extract the data from drop down using python.
[link](https://mahabhunakasha.mahabhumi.gov.in/bhunaksha/27/index.jsp): 
From that,

```
State   
Category    
District    
CTSO    
Division    
Map Type
```

mentions so, I want to extract data from all by selecting one by one using beautifulsoup or request library.

In my code, I gave district name statically but I want to select it one by one and extract data from it.

I tried but it doesn't work
`

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

list = ["Akola", "Amravati", "Buldana", "yavatmal", "washim"]

url = "http://igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx?hDistName="

for lists in list:
    urls= url+lists
    # print(urls)
    response = requests.get(urls)
    # print(response)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    # print(soup)
    # soups= soup.find_all("div", {"id": "level_text_2"})
    # print(soups)

    # for ids in soup.find_all(attrs={'id': 'location_table'}):
    #     print(ids)
    #     ids = ids.text.strip()
    #     print(ids)

    for option in soup.find_all('option'):
        print(option.text)
    for tag in soup.find_all(class_="panel-body"):
        # print(tag.get('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder5_ddlDistrict'))
        print(tag)
`
```

I want:
District name
All taluka names
and all villages name. like that

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for dist_name in ["Akola", "Amravati", "Buldana", "yavatmal", "washim"]:
    print('-- {} --'.format(dist_name))
    r = requests.get('http://igrmaharashtra.gov.in/eASR/eASRCommon.aspx?hDistName={}'.format(dist_name))
    if r.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        select_list = soup.find_all('select')
        for select in select_list:
            print('Select name: ' + select.attrs['name'])
            option_list = select.find_all('option')
            for option in option_list:
                print('\t option: ' + option.attrs['value'])
```

Comment: Actually i dont want to give that` ["Akola", "Amravati", "Buldana", "yavatmal", "washim"]` i want to take that district value dynamically

Comment: @MasterAI It print the value of the option. correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: it will printing only numbers but i want state- maharashtra, catagory-urban/rural, District- name, all talukas from that distirct, Division- all division from that taluka.

Comment: Point to a page that contains this information. Note - I can read only English.

Comment: but the text i.e, district and taluka name in marathi so we can read it with same syntax right